# Do column names have to match variable names in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to build an application with Zend 2.3. It is based on (and very similar to) the [Album application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) of the Zend tutorial. My application deals with Person objects instead of Album objects though.

When I started out, I gave my id column the name 'ID', instead of 'id' like in the tutorial. Consequently, my extractArray function in the Person class looked like this:

```php
public function exchangeArray($data)
{
    $this->id = (isset($data['ID'])) ? $data['ID'] : null; // <- DB column name is ID, not id
    $this->name = (isset($data['name'])) ? $data['name'] : null;
    $this->initials  = (isset($data['initials'])) ? $data['initials'] : null;
    $this->title  = (isset($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
    $this->description  = (isset($data['description'])) ? $data['description'] : null;
    $this->email  = (isset($data['email'])) ? $data['email'] : null;
}
```

I could not get this to work. Adding or deleting a Person went smoothly. But when I tried to edit a Person, it was treated as an insert. After hours of debugging, all I was able to establish is that somewhere during the validation of the form, the Person object's id becomes null, causing the farmework to think that the record is new instead of edited. I really don't know how to be more exact. I did not do anything fancy with the validation of the form, it is exactly like the sample Album application.

After I changed the column name to 'id' and updated the code accordingly, everything works. This would seem to indicate... what, exactly? That DB names have to be lower case? Unlikely. That DB names have to be the same as variable names? Somewhat more likely but seems odd to me.

My question is: what went wrong on my first attempt and was there another way to fix it except changing the column name?

Comment: Please consider showing more code, such as the `editAction`, the `AlbumForm`, the `AlbumModel` ...

Answer (score 0):

not really. The problem then comes when you are trying to save, because you will pass a class and the properties won't match the column name, but for fetch is ok the way you are doing, and it should work.